# heroku can't find javascript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 4 app on Heroku, and all of my assets are loading fine, **except** for my `game.js` file, which is getting a `404 error`. I've looked over multiple threads on this and no answers are seeming to fix it.

```
$ heroku run rails console
> puts helper.asset_path("application.js") 
/game.js
=> nil
```

.gitignore:

```
log/*.log
tmp/**/*
.env
```

gemfile

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

application.js

```
//= require_tree .
```

File Tree

```
_app
|____assets
    |____javascripts
        |____game.js.coffee
```

Comment: Where does `game.js` fall on your file tree? are you sure it's being required in your `application.js` ? Could you add a screenshot of your `app/assets/javascripts` tree and the `application.js` file?

Comment: have you pushed to heroku since adding that file and is it working locally?

Comment: it was in my initial commit.

Comment: if you are using the `rails_12factor gem` there is no reason to set `serve_static_assets` to `true` since this is part of what the `gem` does for you.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that early on, and tried it with false and true and neither works.